# React Router 0.11.1 routes all requests to Home

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having the problem that [React Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) 0.11.1 routes all paths to my default handler, i.e. Home, even though I have a specific handler for the */about* path:

```
var routes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute name="home" handler={Home}/>
    <Route name="about" handler={About}/>
  </Route>
)
ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body)
})
```

Also, the router seems to attach *#/* automatically to the end of the URL, which is confusing. Can someone please tell me how to fix my routing, so that I can access the About handler?

See my full project at [GitHub](https://github.com/aknuds1/chuckdemos/tree/63808b79df21b75f3f08228f13fb17aa203c9891).

Comment: If you want to use the location history API, it seems like you have to do `Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {...});`. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/7355a1821503e642f53fb37e17b66efa52f98d44/UPGRADE_GUIDE.md

Comment: @FelixKling After adding HistoryLocation it works again! Would you mind writing an answer, and detailing why HistoryLocation is necessary??